# Pandas json_normalize when nested objects are null AND not null

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have a file of multiple API responses in json format. They look like this:

```json
{
    "address": "0x1j2jfgn1o2n3b1o3jbo12",
    "risk": "Low",
    "cluster": {
        "name": "foobar",
        "category": "foo"
    },
    "addressIdentifications": []
}
```

Sometimes, that `addressIdentifications` list is populated with one or multiple dicts:

```json
"addressIdentifications": [
        {
            "name": "foobar",
            "category": "scam",
            "description": "description_goes_here"
        }
    ]
```

When calling the API, I load all of the json responses into a list called "data"

```py
data = []
data.append(json.loads(response.text))
```

And then I try to parse and flatten the list into a Pandas Dataframe using `json_normalize`:

```py
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.json_normalize(
        data,
        meta=['address','risk',['cluster','name'],['cluster','category']],
        record_path='addressIdentifications',
        record_prefix='addressIdentification_'))
```

This works fine for the responses where `addressIdentifications` is populated. However, it does not work for those where `addressIdentifications` is just an empty list. It just returns an empty dataframe, not even populating the other columns. In that case, the normal `pd.json_normalize(data)` works fine. But I can't seem to have it both ways.

How can I go through a list of json responses and parse them properly depending on if `addressIdentifications` is populated or not?

Comment: I ran into this exact same problem and @TrentonMcKinney [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63876897/6361531) help me solve my problem.

Comment: Yep! That did it. I looked at so many S/O posts but couldnt find that one. Thank you.

Comment: Great be sure to upvote that post it helped me.  There is an art to searching.  I call it 'Google-Fu'.